# Can I pass additional parameters to JavaScript map() callback function?

Tags: javascript

I have an array and now I want to execute a function on every element in the array.

I'm trying to use `map()` function. The question is, my callback function passed to `map()` has its own parameters (not element, index, array).

Can I pass parameters to such a callback function? How?

Comment: What do you mean? `map((elm, index) => { func(params); })`?

Comment: you can use [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) on your callback function to prepend parameters to your callback, ie your  function would then have a parameter list like `(arg1, arg2, /*etc*/,element,index,array)`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I can think of 2 different ways:

Using `thisArg` to set an options object as the `this` value in the callback:

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function callback(element) {
  return element + this.add;
};

var mapped = numbers.map(callback, {
  add: 10
});

console.log(mapped);
```

Using `.bind()` to set some arguments:

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function callback(add, element) {
  return element + add;
};

var mapped = numbers.map(callback.bind(null, 10));

console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just started to learn Javascript this week. As far as I know, this is a **environment** of a function. For the first solution, I think what you're doing is pass a `this` object to the callback. What is this `this` referring to?

Comment: @Jinglei.Y Usually `this` is used to refer to the object a function is called as a method of. The array map method allows specifying what that `this` object should be, as it is not calling the function as a method this can be very useful. In this case, I just set a specific this value that is my own object. This question goes into more detail on the `this` object: [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Of the 2 I like solution one the best as it avoids the use of bind which seems a bit hacky to me. What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to wrap your original function in another callback function, like this:

```js
var array = ['one', 'two', 'skip-a-few', 'three', 'four']

console.log(
    array.map(function (element) {
        return original('other', 'variables', element)
    })
)


// this function doesn't matter, just an example
function original(a, b, c) {
    return a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c
}
```